# C# Reusing a thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio

I'm wondering how I could *reuse* a thread in c#

```
Thread t = new Thread(() => script(listBox2));
```

The problem I'm having is that after I start the thread, after it preforms the task if I try and *start it again* I get this **error**:

> System.Threading.ThreadStateException: 'Thread is running or
>   terminated; it cannot restart.'

Comment: If you are looking for *pooling*, i.e. *reusing* threads `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) => script(listBox2));`

Comment: You have to remember a thread is not like a script, once it gets to the end and done, its gone, you cant restart it, only make one just like it

Comment: You cannot reuse a thread. The better answer is: do not create your own threads at all. Use Tasks or PoolThreads.

Comment: 'Re-using' a thread is easy.   Loop it and wait for some 'proceed' signal at the top.  Done!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are looking for *pooling* (i.e. *reusing*) threads; if it's your case, try use 
[ThreadPool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbf0f1ct(v=vs.110).aspx) static class which has been specially designed for this:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) => script(listBox2));

...

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) => otherScript(listboxN));
```